# Can't Save coordinates vars from Google Map [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
<script>
var lat ;
if(true) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
        function GetLocation(location) {
            var lat = location.coords.latitude;
        }           
};  

alert(lat);
 </script>
```

Now I get [object HTMLInputElement] , am I doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: You have not provide enough information to answer your question.  There are no HTLMInputElements obvious in that snippet.

Comment: ok I will post the whole source code here , https://gist.github.com/6d722366ba84ccfeb36f , I just can't pass the variable somehow, i don't know what's wrong here . thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are declaring a variable with the same name in your function, this means you have two variables, a global one and a local one. So when you alert the global variable it hasn't been set to anything.

All you need to do is remove the var keyword from your function:

```
// global or other scope

var lat, firstUpdate = false;

if(true) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetLocation);
    function GetLocation(location) {

        // don't use var here, that will make a local variable
        lat = location.coords.latitude;

        // this will run only on the first time we get a location.
        if(firstUpdate == false){
           doSomething();
           firstUpdate = true;
        }

    }           
};  

function doSomething(){
    alert(lat);
}
```

**Edit:**

I have edited the answer to show how you can make sure you call a function once you have found your first fix.

Comment: I changed that but still not working, check out the file https://gist.github.com/a08f2da0ec1acafbe48d , this is the html and how it looks like , now i'm getting **undefined** error

Comment: at least i'm supposed to get a string 'location.coords.longitude' as a message but i can't access the msg somehow , no clue why ?

Comment: I think the alert will get called before the GetLocation function has called back, can you trace or alert the location in the GetLocation function?

Comment: u r absolutely right here, when i call it from within the function it will work, but i need to save the variable tho and use it later on with something else, any workaround to solve such a situation ?

Comment: thanks for trying to help Neil but still not working, to make it very clear, i just created a simple html (https://gist.github.com/6b15b3da7f4b941c1069) and still can't get the alert message, any clue ?